# API do Google Maps que traz os locais próximos

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, localização

Conhecem alguma API do Google Maps que traz os locais próximos à localização informada, como comércio, lazer, etc?

Desde já, obrigado.

Comment: O que você procura: [Creating a Store Locator on Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator)